# Reticle not detecting button

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have 4 buttons (called 'paintings' here) and I need the gvr reticle to be able to click on each. The funny thing is, the reticle works on three of the buttons, just not the 'south' one.
[image]

My FirstPersonCharacter has a Main Camera with the GvrReticle.

[image]

Things I've tried:

- deleting my existing south button and replacing it with a duplicate of one of the working buttons
- disabling the other 3 buttons
- moving the canvas and button off the wall

All of the painting-buttons come from the same prefab and I didn't make any changes to the south one, so I don't think the problem is with the painting-button itself.

Let me know if there's more information I can provide to help pinpoint the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set PaintingSouth's rotation to 180. When I looked carefully at the four paintings, I could tell PaintingSouth's text was backwards. I guess if your button is facing the wrong way on a canvas, the reticle doesn't detect it?

Anyway, I hope this helps someone. I shall not forget this day.

Comment: HAHAHAHA. I know this was almost two years ago but I found this question because my button was not working. Yep flipped Y 180 degrees and now it works!

Comment: Glad this helped :)